# How do I pass data from one Fragment to a subfragment defined in xml?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a viewpager populated with fragments.

One of these fragments has a subfragment defined in xml.

How do I pass data from the fragment to its subfragment (if that is possible) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a reference to the fragment from the `FragmentManager` using either `findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`.

Alternatively, you might find that it's easier to instantiate the fragment programatically and give it arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments from one fragment to other while setting the fragment programatically.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key", 0);
myfragment.setArguments(bundle);
```